# Applying exponential of a logarithm to solve limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I solve this problem: 
$\lim_{x\to\infty} (-x +\sqrt{x^2+1})^{1/\ln x}$

Edit: I knew how I had to apply exponentials and logarithms but was unsure of how to work the limits of the exponent. Is this in the picture right?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV6Zt.png)
 Note: I applied L'hopital and despised 1 because of the infinities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)^{1/\log(x)}&=\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{\frac{-\log\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}{\log(x)}}\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{-\frac{\log(x)+\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\right)}{\log(x)}}\\\\
&=e^{-1} \lim_{x\to 0}\,e^{-\frac{\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\right)}{\log(x)}}\\\\
&=e^{-1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Heya, I was wondering how the very last step works; how do you reason that $\lim e^{-\ln/\ln}=1$?
Edit: lim e, not limes.

Comment: @jam The numerator approaches $\log(2)$ while the denominator approaches infinity.  The ratio approaches zero.  And $e^0=1$.

Comment: Nice one, thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: Where did that e^-1 came from?  If you factored it out and then shouldn't the other part be left positive?

Comment: @D.Madrid $$e^{-\frac{\log(x)+\log\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\right)}{\log(x)}}=e^{-\frac{\log(x)}{\log(x)}}\times e^{-\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\right)}{\log(x)}}=e^{-1}\times e^{-\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\right)}{\log(x)}}$$

Comment: There is supposed to be a log in the numerator right?... But thank you very much, *basic algebra* haha

Comment: @D.Madrid Yes.  Two typographical errors in the comment.

Comment: @D.Madrid You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$y=\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)^{\frac{1}{\log (x)}}$$ and take logarithms first $$\log(y)=\frac{1}{\log (x)}\log\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$$ Now, consider that $$\sqrt{x^2+1}-x=x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1\right)$$ $$\log\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=\log(x)+\log\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1\right)$$ Now, for small $x$, Taylor series (or generalized binomial expansion) gives $$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=1+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$ $$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1=\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ $$\log\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}-1\right)=-\log(2)-2\log(x)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ $$\log\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=-\log(2)-\log(x)+O\left(\frac{1}{x ^2}\right)$$ $$\log(y)=-\frac {\log(x)+\log(2)}{\log(x)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=-1-\frac {\log(2)}{\log(x)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ which, for $\log(y)$, shows the limit and how it is approached. Now, remember that $y=e^{\log(y)}$.

Comment: This was a huge help because I would never have thought of doing that. It is amazing how far series can take you. Thank you very much. So the answer is e^-1?
What does the O mean :/?

Comment: @D.Madrid. Don't worry : you will learn it soon. Meanwhile, have a look at   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation